# Virtual Box 5.1.22 Installation Failure

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, dependencies

each time i try install the virtualbox 5.1.22 application it fails because of the following dependencies:

Please help.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-5.1 : Depends: libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.6.0~beta) but 5.4.2+dfsg-2ubuntu9 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.6.0~beta) but 5.4.2+dfsg-2ubuntu9 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libvpx3 (>= 1.5.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: pdf-viewer
```

Comment: You seem to be using an EOL version of Ubuntu; you have version `5.4.2+dfsg-2ubuntu9` of `libqt5core5a`, but [it is not present in any currently supported version of Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt5core5a&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the first step try this commands to add universe and multiverse repositories for some libraries:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then try this command to remove previews libraries:

```
sudo dpkg -r libqt5core5a libqt5widgets5
```

Then try to install depends libraries:

```
sudo apt install libpng16-16 libqt5core5a libqt5printsupport5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5
sudo apt -f install
```

And then try to install virtualbox:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

Comment: My apologies for the late response Ali76, your solution worked great. Thank you. Much appreciated